# Why can't my node js script connect to my mssql database running in docker, but Microsoft SQL Server Management can

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to connect node js script to MsSQL database server, but fails.

My Microsoft SQL Server Management is however able to connect to the database.

node.js code

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {  
    server: "172.168.200.35",
    dialect: "mssql",
    port:51433,
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'testuser',
            password: 'abc123'
        }
    },
    options: {
        database: 'IoTDb'
    }
};  
var connection = new Connection(config);  
// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on("connect", err => {
if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
} else {
    executeStatement();
}
});
```

When running the code, I get this error

`Failed to connect to 172.168.200.35:51433:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 172.168.200.35:51433`

I don't understand why its fails to connect port `1433`, as the port is defined as `51433`

However, when I try to connect to the database via this login info (same as node config variable)
[image]

It connects and I get this view over the database
[image]

For info about the database, it is running via docker on another pc, but is reachable

I moved the `port` to `options` and now the error is this

`Failed to connect to 172.168.200.35:51433:51433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 172.168.200.35:51433`

Comment: SSMS is nothing more than a client application, just like your application. If one succeeds and the other fails, the problem is in the code.

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn't nodejs connect to `51433` not `1433`

Comment: In my config variable, I have defined the port as `51433`

Comment: The error says `Failed to connect to 172.168.200.35:1433`. That's not the same port. Are you sure you set the correct parameter?

Comment: I see. I added the port to the server in node and the new error can be seen

Comment: Don't try random things. They won't work. The `port` attribute doesn't go to the root, it goes to `options`

Comment: Per the [docs](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_newConnection), the `port` field is part of the `options` field and can't be put directly in the `config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this issue shows](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/119) the port should be specified in `options`:

```
var config = {  
    server: "172.168.200.35",
    dialect: "mssql",
...
    options: {
        database: 'IoTDb',
        port:51433,
    }
};
```